# Date axis label visibility problem in trading view lightwight

Tags: javascript, html, charts, tradingview-api

I want to create HLOC chart with `trading view lightweight`. Everything is OK and I can pass data with ajax to chart.
this is my html with java scripts:

**index.html**

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #222">
    <div id="tw-container-1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%">

    </div>
</body>
```

**my_scripts.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const container = document.getElementById('tw-container-1');
    const chart_height = window.innerHeight - 50;
    const chart_width = window.innerWidth - 50;

    function generateCandlestickData() {
        return [
            {
                time: "2018-10-19",
                open: 180.34,
                high: 180.99,
                low: 178.57,
                close: 179.85,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-10-22",
                open: 180.82,
                high: 181.4,
                low: 177.56,
                close: 178.75,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-10-23",
                open: 175.77,
                high: 179.49,
                low: 175.44,
                close: 178.53,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-10-24",
                open: 178.58,
                high: 182.37,
                low: 176.31,
                close: 176.97,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-10-25",
                open: 177.52,
                high: 180.5,
                low: 176.83,
                close: 179.07,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-10-26",
                open: 176.88,
                high: 177.34,
                low: 170.91,
                close: 172.23,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-10-29",
                open: 173.74,
                high: 175.99,
                low: 170.95,
                close: 173.2,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-10-30",
                open: 173.16,
                high: 176.43,
                low: 172.64,
                close: 176.24,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-10-31",
                open: 177.98,
                high: 178.85,
                low: 175.59,
                close: 175.88,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-01",
                open: 176.84,
                high: 180.86,
                low: 175.9,
                close: 180.46,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-02",
                open: 182.47,
                high: 183.01,
                low: 177.39,
                close: 179.93,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-05",
                open: 181.02,
                high: 182.41,
                low: 179.3,
                close: 182.19,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-06",
                open: 181.93,
                high: 182.65,
                low: 180.05,
                close: 182.01,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-07",
                open: 183.79,
                high: 187.68,
                low: 182.06,
                close: 187.23,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-08",
                open: 187.13,
                high: 188.69,
                low: 185.72,
                close: 188.0,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-09",
                open: 188.32,
                high: 188.48,
                low: 184.96,
                close: 185.99,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-12",
                open: 185.23,
                high: 186.95,
                low: 179.02,
                close: 179.43,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-13",
                open: 177.3,
                high: 181.62,
                low: 172.85,
                close: 179.0,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-14",
                open: 182.61,
                high: 182.9,
                low: 179.15,
                close: 179.9,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-15",
                open: 179.01,
                high: 179.67,
                low: 173.61,
                close: 177.36,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-16",
                open: 173.99,
                high: 177.6,
                low: 173.51,
                close: 177.02,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-19",
                open: 176.71,
                high: 178.88,
                low: 172.3,
                close: 173.59,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-20",
                open: 169.25,
                high: 172.0,
                low: 167.0,
                close: 169.05,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-21",
                open: 170.0,
                high: 170.93,
                low: 169.15,
                close: 169.3,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-23",
                open: 169.39,
                high: 170.33,
                low: 168.47,
                close: 168.85,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-26",
                open: 170.2,
                high: 172.39,
                low: 168.87,
                close: 169.82,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-27",
                open: 169.11,
                high: 173.38,
                low: 168.82,
                close: 173.22,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-28",
                open: 172.91,
                high: 177.65,
                low: 170.62,
                close: 177.43,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-29",
                open: 176.8,
                high: 177.27,
                low: 174.92,
                close: 175.66,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-11-30",
                open: 175.75,
                high: 180.37,
                low: 175.11,
                close: 180.32,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-03",
                open: 183.29,
                high: 183.5,
                low: 179.35,
                close: 181.74,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-04",
                open: 181.06,
                high: 182.23,
                low: 174.55,
                close: 175.3,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-06",
                open: 173.5,
                high: 176.04,
                low: 170.46,
                close: 175.96,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-07",
                open: 175.35,
                high: 178.36,
                low: 172.24,
                close: 172.79,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-10",
                open: 173.39,
                high: 173.99,
                low: 167.73,
                close: 171.69,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-11",
                open: 174.3,
                high: 175.6,
                low: 171.24,
                close: 172.21,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-12",
                open: 173.75,
                high: 176.87,
                low: 172.81,
                close: 174.21,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-13",
                open: 174.31,
                high: 174.91,
                low: 172.07,
                close: 173.87,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-14",
                open: 172.98,
                high: 175.14,
                low: 171.95,
                close: 172.29,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-17",
                open: 171.51,
                high: 171.99,
                low: 166.93,
                close: 167.97,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-18",
                open: 168.9,
                high: 171.95,
                low: 168.5,
                close: 170.04,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-19",
                open: 170.92,
                high: 174.95,
                low: 166.77,
                close: 167.56,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-20",
                open: 166.28,
                high: 167.31,
                low: 162.23,
                close: 164.16,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-21",
                open: 162.81,
                high: 167.96,
                low: 160.17,
                close: 160.48,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-24",
                open: 160.16,
                high: 161.4,
                low: 158.09,
                close: 158.14,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-26",
                open: 159.46,
                high: 168.28,
                low: 159.44,
                close: 168.28,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-27",
                open: 166.44,
                high: 170.46,
                low: 163.36,
                close: 170.32,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-28",
                open: 171.22,
                high: 173.12,
                low: 168.6,
                close: 170.22,
            },
            {
                time: "2018-12-31",
                open: 171.47,
                high: 173.24,
                low: 170.65,
                close: 171.82,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-02",
                open: 169.71,
                high: 173.18,
                low: 169.05,
                close: 172.41,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-03",
                open: 171.84,
                high: 171.84,
                low: 168.21,
                close: 168.61,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-04",
                open: 170.18,
                high: 174.74,
                low: 169.52,
                close: 173.62,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-07",
                open: 173.83,
                high: 178.18,
                low: 173.83,
                close: 177.04,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-08",
                open: 178.57,
                high: 179.59,
                low: 175.61,
                close: 177.89,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-09",
                open: 177.87,
                high: 181.27,
                low: 177.1,
                close: 179.73,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-10",
                open: 178.03,
                high: 179.24,
                low: 176.34,
                close: 179.06,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-11",
                open: 177.93,
                high: 180.26,
                low: 177.12,
                close: 179.41,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-14",
                open: 177.59,
                high: 179.23,
                low: 176.9,
                close: 178.81,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-15",
                open: 176.08,
                high: 177.82,
                low: 175.2,
                close: 176.47,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-16",
                open: 177.09,
                high: 177.93,
                low: 175.86,
                close: 177.04,
            },
            {
                time: "2019-01-17",
                open: 174.01,
                high: 175.46,
                low: 172.0,
                close: 174.87,
            },
        ]
    }



    // Create the Lightweight Chart within the container element
    const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(
        container,
        {
            width: chart_width,
            height: chart_height,
            layout: {
                background: { color: "#222" },
                textColor: "#C3BCDB",
            },
            grid: {
                vertLines: { color: "#444" },
                horzLines: { color: "#444" },
            },
        }
    );

    // Setting the border color for the vertical axis
    chart.priceScale().applyOptions({
        borderColor: "#71649C",
    });

    // Setting the border color for the horizontal axis
    chart.timeScale().applyOptions({
        borderColor: "#71649C",
    });

    // Adjust the starting bar width (essentially the horizontal zoom)
    chart.timeScale().applyOptions({
        barSpacing: 10,
    });


    // Customizing the Crosshair
    chart.applyOptions({
        crosshair: {
            // Change mode from default 'magnet' to 'normal'.
            // Allows the crosshair to move freely without snapping to datapoints
            mode: LightweightCharts.CrosshairMode.Normal,

            // Vertical crosshair line (showing Date in Label)
            vertLine: {
                width: 100,
                color: "#C3BCDB44",
                style: LightweightCharts.LineStyle.Solid,
                labelBackgroundColor: "#9B7DFF",
            },

            // Horizontal crosshair line (showing Price in Label)
            horzLine: {
                color: "#9B7DFF",
                labelBackgroundColor: "#9B7DFF",
            },
        },
    });

    // Adding a window resize event handler to resize the chart when
    // the window size changes.
    // Note: for more advanced examples (when the chart doesn't fill the entire window)
    // you may need to use ResizeObserver -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        chart.resize(chart_width, chart_height);
    });

    const trade_hloc_chart = chart.addCandlestickSeries();
    trade_hloc_chart.setData(generateCandlestickData());

    // Changing the Candlestick colors
    trade_hloc_chart.applyOptions({
        wickUpColor: "rgb(54, 116, 217)",
        upColor: "rgb(54, 116, 217)",
        wickDownColor: "rgb(225, 50, 85)",
        downColor: "rgb(225, 50, 85)",
        borderVisible: false,
    });

    // Adjust the options for the priceScale of the mainSeries
    trade_hloc_chart.priceScale().applyOptions({
        autoScale: false, // disables auto scaling based on visible content
        scaleMargins: {
            top: 0.1,
            bottom: 0.2,
        },
    });

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        chart.resize(chart_width, chart_height);
    });

    chart.timeScale().fitContent();
</script>
```

**The problem is in the label of date axis: the label doesn't visible** (I think the problem has been created because of `z-index`).
Here is screenshot of index page:
[image]

As you can see half of the date label is shown.
The version of trading view is  `TradingView-lightweight-3.8.0`.

**How can fix that? Thanks for your helps.**